# Carry out action only after firestore collection is returned

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am subscribing to a collection in firestore. I want to carry out some action on that data once the value is returned. What is the best way to do this? I came across a similar question that led me to write the code below. However, that code appears not to wait until a value is present.

```
this.versionCollection = this.FirebaseService.getCollection('versions', 'projectId', this.projectData.uid )
.subscribe(()=>{

    // Actions to be carried out after the data is returned
    this.versionData = this.versionCollection[this.versionCollection.length];
    this.initializeMenu();
    this.initializeModel();

});
```

The code called in the service where afs is AngularFirestore ...

```
getCollection( collection, paramName, paramValue ) {
    return this.afs.collection( collection, ref => ref.where( paramName, '==', paramValue )).valueChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple if check like below will do the job.

```
this.versionCollection = this.FirebaseService.getCollection('versions', 'projectId', this.projectData.uid )
    .subscribe(()=>{

        if(this.versionCollection) {
          this.versionData = this.versionCollection[this.versionCollection.length];
          this.initializeMenu();
          this.initializeModel();
        }

    });
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. However, I still had a problem getting the data from the observable. In the end, I used a different technique - one that it less elegant, but more understandable. I feel like I am missing something here with how firestore is supposed to be used.